# Javascript Media Query

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a media query using JavaScript because the browser I'm designing for doesn't support it. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong and I've exhausted my options anyways here is my code

```
if(window.innerWidth > 1000 && window.innerWidth < 1300) {

    document.getElementById('id').style.height="50px";

 }
```

Comment: I'd say so be it.If it's a desktop browser why does it need to support responsive design? responsive design makes sense for mobile web,where design needs to adapt the mobile form factor.It makes little sense for desktop browsers.

Comment: so... if window.innerWidth > 1300... do you really need to check that it's also > 1000?  Anyways, it would help if we knew what browser you are designing for.

Comment: I'm designing for IE versions 8 to 10 it's mostly a real estate problem and I need to prevent some scaling issues that are occurring. My plan is to add a simple style to correct the issue but I cannot use media queries. Also the numbers are arbitrary. I am just wondering if this route would work.

Comment: if(innerWidth > 1000){ document.body.className+=" wide"; } then, you can make any css rule kick in only for that by pre-pending "body.wide " to the existing selector. makes more sense than hard-coding a bunch of element stuff in JS, and lets you define all the look in CSS, which is good separation of concerns.

Comment: Sorry this is my first post, I'm designing for Microsoft SharePoint 10 So I don't have much freedom with the html or css class. i Should have mentioned this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are asking your browser to change the height of your element if the width is bigger than 1000 AND 1300. This can't work. You can try something like this:

```
if(window.innerWidth > 1000) {

    document.getElementById('id').style.height="50px";

}
```

I think what you are asking is this:

```
if(window.innerWidth > 1000 && window.innerHeight > 1300) {

    document.getElementById('id').style.height="50px";

}
```

For better results you should add an event listener

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if(window.innerWidth > 1000 && window.innerHeight > 1300) {
        document.getElementById('id').style.height="50px";
    }
};
```